# Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Sleeping issues after upgrade

Tags: suspend, 22.04, lid

When I close my laptop it sometimes hangs after trying to suspend.

Kernel version is 5.15.0-41-generic.

Ubuntu Version is Ubuntu 22.04 LTS & I upgraded from Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Half of time it works.

syslog says about "suspend":

```
Aug  7 09:35:37 Marcus-HP-ProBook kernel: [    1.768592] nvme 0000:04:00.0: platform quirk: setting simple suspend
Aug  7 19:22:38 Marcus-HP-ProBook kernel: [    1.186164] nvme 0000:04:00.0: platform quirk: setting simple suspend
Aug  7 22:53:13 Marcus-HP-ProBook kernel: [    1.172256] nvme 0000:04:00.0: platform quirk: setting simple suspend
Aug  8 07:56:25 Marcus-HP-ProBook kernel: [32687.712543] PM: suspend entry (deep)
Aug  8 08:41:09 Marcus-HP-ProBook kernel: [32687.992303] printk: Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)
Aug  8 08:41:09 Marcus-HP-ProBook kernel: [32689.691219] PM: suspend exit
Aug  8 22:54:53 Marcus-HP-ProBook kernel: [    2.079363] nvme 0000:04:00.0: platform quirk: setting simple suspend
Aug  9 11:02:16 Marcus-HP-ProBook kernel: [    1.176866] nvme 0000:04:00.0: platform quirk: setting simple suspend
Aug  9 16:55:43 Marcus-HP-ProBook kernel: [21301.601281] PM: suspend entry (deep)
Aug  9 18:51:57 Marcus-HP-ProBook kernel: [21301.916050] printk: Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)
Aug  9 18:51:57 Marcus-HP-ProBook kernel: [21303.552745] PM: suspend exit
Aug  9 20:51:56 Marcus-HP-ProBook kernel: [    1.825891] nvme 0000:04:00.0: platform quirk: setting simple suspend
Aug 10 00:50:27 Marcus-HP-ProBook kernel: [14407.045343] PM: suspend entry (deep)
Aug 10 08:55:58 Marcus-HP-ProBook kernel: [14407.401678] printk: Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)
Aug 10 08:55:58 Marcus-HP-ProBook kernel: [14409.054763] PM: suspend exit
Aug 10 09:30:11 Marcus-HP-ProBook kernel: [    1.799155] nvme 0000:04:00.0: platform quirk: setting simple suspend
Aug 10 17:27:09 Marcus-HP-ProBook kernel: [    1.843817] nvme 0000:04:00.0: platform quirk: setting simple suspend
Aug 10 23:24:57 Marcus-HP-ProBook kernel: [21562.492097] PM: suspend entry (deep)
Aug 11 09:54:22 Marcus-HP-ProBook kernel: [    1.226800] nvme 0000:04:00.0: platform quirk: setting simple suspend
Aug 11 11:55:41 Marcus-HP-ProBook kernel: [    2.061767] nvme 0000:04:00.0: platform quirk: setting simple suspend
Aug 11 11:57:42 Marcus-HP-ProBook kernel: [  217.436971] PM: suspend entry (deep)
Aug 11 11:57:46 Marcus-HP-ProBook kernel: [  217.841330] printk: Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)
Aug 11 11:57:46 Marcus-HP-ProBook kernel: [  219.501065] PM: suspend exit
Aug 11 11:58:27 Marcus-HP-ProBook kernel: [  260.794194] PM: suspend entry (deep)
Aug 11 11:58:38 Marcus-HP-ProBook kernel: [  260.989718] printk: Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)
Aug 11 11:58:38 Marcus-HP-ProBook kernel: [  262.648178] PM: suspend exit
Aug 11 12:04:15 Marcus-HP-ProBook kernel: [    2.595887] nvme 0000:04:00.0: platform quirk: setting simple suspend
Aug 11 12:05:31 Marcus-HP-ProBook kernel: [  174.020178] PM: suspend entry (deep)
Aug 11 12:05:34 Marcus-HP-ProBook kernel: [  174.260753] printk: Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)
Aug 11 12:05:34 Marcus-HP-ProBook kernel: [  175.944074] PM: suspend exit
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: @user535733 OK i edited into my question

Comment: Take a look at https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=215742. If it's not the problem you have, you can see the troubleshooting procedure you should follow.